# How to use random_shuffle to shuffle a 2D array C++

Tags: c++, random, shuffle

I have a 2D vector of objects and I want to shuffle them. What is the syntax for this?

```
    class node{
    public:
        string hex_type = "E";// empty to start
        int Xcoordinate;
        int Ycoordinate;
        vector<reference_wrapper<node>> neighbors;


    };
nodes = vector<vector<node> >(size, vector <node>(size));//filled elsewhere
random_shuffle(&nodes[0][0], &nodes[size-1][size-1]);
```

This generates an error that is is an access violation reading

Comment: Lets start with the array. Is it a **real** 2D array and not some trumped up pointer array ? if so, your close with your second attempt.

Comment: it's a real 2D array of objects, yes, not pointers.

Comment: What was the problem with your second attempt?

Comment: it didn't actually do anything. And I seeded it with srand(time(NULL))

Comment: Just for what it's worth, you might want to use `std::shuffle` instead of `std::random_shuffle`. `std::shuffle` was added in C++11, and as of C++14, it appears that `std::random_shuffle` will be officially deprecated.

Comment: You might be interested in watching [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) so that you, at the very least, stop using `srand(time(NULL))`.

Comment: Note: `a.begin()` is a not-so-subtle hint this is *not* a *real* 2D **array**. It is a `std::vector` of something (maybe `std::array`, maybe `std:vector`, maybe something else). They're *not* synonymous. You should update your title to be "How to use random_shuffle to shuffle a vector of <<whatever your inner container is here>>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2d array a n x m, you can put it in a 1d array b n x m like this:

```
b[i * m + j] = a[i][j];
```

Then you can shuffle array b and user reverse transformation

```
a[i / m][i % m] = b[i];
```